# Range slider input event not firing in IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

I have a range slider and I want to listen to its `change` and `input` events. This works fine in most browsers, but in IE 10, there is no `input` event firing and `change` fires over and over like `input` is supposed to. Here is the code:

html:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" />
```

js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var input = document.getElementById('slider');

  input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    console.log('input');
  });

  input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log('change');
  });

});
```

And here it is on codepen: http://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/YPQVzJ

I'm wondering if there is a workaround for this - a polyfill or some simple trick.

Comment: I am having no issue with IE10 Range slider. Do verify that you are in IE 10 / 11 by hitting F12 and viewing the version

Comment: @CayceK yeah I'm in IE 10 - are you seeing 'input' logged in your console?

Comment: As a workaround, I’d probably try with a timeout on the change event – assuming that when the “constant” firing of change will stop for a certain amount of time, that means the user is done moving the slider, and this can therefor be considered the time to (manually) trigger the input event. (Similar to what Resig suggests here, http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/)

Comment: Is the element registering the event being fired? Console log is your best friend for debugging

Comment: cool - thanks @CBroe that may be what I have to end up doing...

Comment: Zevan... when I put my comment there wasn't as much information about your input and so on so forth, but the answer is yes based on the original codepen there were logs recording. I was under the assumption originally that it wasn't showing up at all.

Comment: oh - gotcha @Cayce K

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured this out a few days ago and figured I'd post my solution. Basically the trick is to check if you're in IE (using your sniffing method of choice). Then hijack the `change` event for `range` inputs and fire an `input` instead. Then, fire a `change` on `mouseup`. This seems to work great so far:

(here's a pen http://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/pvWzej)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  var input = document.getElementById('slider');

  input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    console.log('input');
  });

  input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log('change');
  });

  var fixInputAndChangeEvents = function() {
    var currentSlider;
    var fireChange = function(e) {
      var changeEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
      changeEvent.initEvent('change', true, true);

      changeEvent.forceChange = true;
      currentSlider.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
    };

    document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      var inputEvent;
      if (!e.forceChange && e.target.getAttribute('type') === 'range') {
        e.stopPropagation();
        inputEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
        inputEvent.initEvent('input', true, true);

        e.target.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

        currentSlider = e.target;
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', fireChange);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', fireChange);
      }

    }, true); // make sure we're in the capture phase
  };

  var isIE = function() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    return userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 ||  
      userAgent.indexOf('Trident') !== -1;
  };

  if (isIE()) {
    fixInputAndChangeEvents();
  }

});
```

There are a few things I changed in the actual version I used on the project I'm working on.

1. The project uses lodash so at the request of another developer I partialized the `fireChange` event and passed the current `range` input as the first argument rather than just using the `currentSlider` variable. This is basically to avoid collisions - pretty sure a collision isn't possible since you can only slide one slider at a time, but we figured better be safe than sorry.
2. The project already had IE sniffing, so I used what was already there over what you see here.

It would be nice to somehow figure out if this event behavior exists rather than sniffing for IE, but I couldn't quite figure out how to determine if the event flaw was present.

Anyway, hope that helps if someone else encounters this problem. I think there is still some room for improvement but this works good enough for now.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

As mentionned in comment by Justin Smith, IE10 not support conditionnal comment anymore.

> [Conditional comments are no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

So the code below is correct under IE10 (I will remove bad comment), and this post not respond to the original answer.

ORIGINAL:

With this code, you will be able to do what you want with your ie version:

If your browser is not one of IE version, no `ie` class will be found on `html` tag. Also, an `ie` class will be found and also an `ieX` version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]><html lang="fr" class="ie ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html lang="fr" class="ie ie10"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="fr" class="ie ie11"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html lang="fr"><!--<![endif]-->
```

and below you have:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" />
```

After that, into your code, just do that:

- Fire `input` for all browser.
- Fire `change` for all ie.

So

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
    slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
    input = (html.classList.contains("ie")) "change" : "input";

slider.addEventListener(input, function () {
    // Do something;
});
```

Comment: This wont' work. The question specifically states that the problem is with IE10, which doesn't support condition tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I consider to be better than anything I've seen so far on this topic because it doesn't require you to check what browser you're in.

Basically instead of checking for input, you check for mousedown, set an interval, then on mouseup you clear the interval.

```
var dragInterval = function dragInterval() {
        console.log(event);
    }, 10);
};

rangeInput.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    dragInterval();
});
rangeInput.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    clearInterval(dragInterval);
});
```

Comment: ok but you'd also want to cover arrow keying etc on the element